# Is ReferenceEquals(null, obj) the same thing as null == obj?

Tags: c#

Is it the same thing?

```
if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
```

and

```
if (null == obj) return false;
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You'd usually see this in the implementation of an == operator.

For instance:

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo f1, Foo f2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(f1, f2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(f1, null) || ReferenceEquals(f2, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Now do comparisons
}
```

You don't want to use:

```
if (f1 == f2)
```

because that will recurse into the same code! An alternative is:

```
if ((object)f1 == (object)f2)
```

(And the same for the null check.)

Answer (score 19):

It is the same thing if `obj` is typed as `object`.

If the **variable**'s type defines a static equality operator or null operator, then it will be different; and if `obj` is defined as `Nullable<T>` then the compiler will step in and check `HasValue` instead.