# Whats the Difference between Object.Equals(obj, null) and obj == null

Tags: c#, reference, null, equals

Almost every time I want to check object's equality to `null` I use the normal equality check operation

```
if (obj == null)
```

Recently I noticed that I'm using the `Object.Equals()` more often

```
if (Object.Equals(obj, null))
```

and while reading about null checking I fount this [Is ReferenceEquals(null, obj) the same thing as null == obj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970334/is-referenceequalsnull-obj-the-same-thing-as-null-obj)

```
if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
```

Whats the difference? and where/when to use each one? plus I found that the last two checks look like the same according to their `summary`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Object.Equals(x, y)` will:

- Return true if `x` and `y` are both null
- Return false if exactly one of `x` or `y` is null
- Otherwise call either `x.Equals(y)` or `y.Equals(x)` - it *shouldn't* matter which. This means that whatever polymorphic behaviour has been implemented by the *execution-time* type of the object `x` or `y` refers to will be invoked.

`ReferenceEquals` will *not* call the polymorphic `Equals` method. It *just* compares references for equality. For example:

```
string x = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();
string y = new StringBuilder("hello").ToString();
Console.WriteLine(Object.Equals(x, y)); // True
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)); // False
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // True due to overloading
```

Now if you're *only* checking for nullity, then you don't really *want* the polymorphic behaviour - just reference equality. So feel free to use `ReferenceEquals`.

You could *also* use `==`, but that can be *overloaded* (not overridden) by classes - it is in the case of string, as shown above. The most common case for using `ReferenceEquals` in my experience is when you're *implementing* `==`:

```
public bool operator ==(Foo x1, Foo x2)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(x1, x2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(x1, null) || ReferenceEquals(x2, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return x1.Equals(x2);
}
```

Here you really *don't* want to call the `==` implementation, because it would recurse forever - you want the very definite reference equality semantics.

Comment: how do you alter the content of a post with out having it show as edited?

Comment: @Rune: If you edit it within the first 5 minutes of posting, it doesn't show up.